# I would like to split a word string into different individual letters

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to create a morse code generator. I want to split a sentence into individual letter strings, and input it in my function, but I don't know how to do it.

```
var count='';
function cc(card){
   switch(card){
       case 'A':count+='.- '
       break;
       case 'B':count+='-...   '
       break;
       case 'C':count+='-.-.   '
       break;
       case 'D':count+='-..    '
       break;
       case 'E':count+=' . '
       break;
       case 'F':count+='..-.   '
       break;
       case 'G':count+='--.    '
       break;
       case 'H':count+='....   '
       break;
       case 'I':count+='.. '
       break;
       case 'J':count+='.---   '
       break;
       case 'K':count+='-.-    '
       break;
       case 'L':count+='.-..   '
       break;
       case 'M':count+='-- '
       break;
       case 'N':count+='-.'
       break;
       case 'O':count+='---    '
       break;
       case 'P':count+='.--.   '
       break;
       case 'Q':count+='--.-   '
       break;
       case 'R':count+='.-.    '
       break;
       case 'S':count+='...    '
       break;
       case 'T':count+='-'
       break;
       case 'U':count+='..-    '
       break;
       case 'V':count+='...-   '
       break;
       case 'W':count+='.--    '
       break;
       case 'X':count+='-..-   '
       break;
       case 'Y':count+='-.--   '
       break;
       case 'Z':count+='--..   '
       break;
       case 1:count+='.----    '
       break;
       case 2:count+='..---    '
       break;
       case 3:count+='...--    '
       break;
       case 4:count+='....-    '
       break;
       case 5:count+='.....    '
       break;
       case 6:count+='-....    '
       break;
       case 7:count+='--...    '
       break;
       case 8:count+='---..    '
       break;
       case 9:count+='----.    '
       break;
       case 10:count+='.----   ,-----  '
       break;
       case 0:count+='-----    '
       break;
   }
   return count;
}

console.log(cc("A"));
```

Comment: You can split a string into an array of characters with `.split("")`, e.g. `"Hello World".split("")`

Comment: Unrelated tip: when you write in ALL-CAPITALS it comes off as yelling (and rude). You should avoid that.

Comment: The code is reflecting your question above. Are you trying to convert string to morse code? If you, then something like should help `text.split('').map(convertor).join('')`, where converter is function that gets the each character of the text.

Answer (score 2):

Refering to this article https://www.tutorialspoint.com/converting-string-to-morse-code-in-javascript

This is a working function for converting a string into morse code:

```
const morseCode = {
   "A": ".-",
   "B": "-...",
   "C": "-.-.",
   "D": "-..",
   "E": ".",
   "F": "..-.",
   "G": "--.",
   "H": "....",
   "I": "..",
   "J": ".---",
   "K": "-.-",
   "L": ".-..",
   "M": "--",
   "N": "-.",
   "O": "---",
   "P": ".--.",
   "Q": "--.-",
   "R": ".-.",
   "S": "...",
   "T": "-",
   "U": "..-",
   "W": ".--",
   "X": "-..-",
   "Y": "-.--",
   "Z": "--.."
}
const convertToMorse = (str) => {
   return str.toUpperCase().split("").map(el => {
      return morseCode[el] ? morseCode[el] : el;
   }).join("");
};
console.log(convertToMorse('Disaster management'));
console.log(convertToMorse('hey there!'));
```

**Edit:**

As a direct answer to your question, you can use `.split("")` to create an Array of one-letter strings. With that you could then use `.forEach()` to execute your function with each individual letter.

Example:

```
let yourSentence = "HELLO WORLD";

yourSentence.split("").forEach(letter => {
cc(letter);
});
console.log(count);
```

If your string uses lowercase characters you can use `.toUpperCase()` on your string as follows to make it work with your function:

```
let uppercaseSentence = yourSentence.toUpperCase();
```

This will capitalize each letter in your sentence to make it work with your function.

Example with lowercase characters:

```
const yourSentence = "Hello World";

let uppercaseSentence = yourSentence.toUpperCase();

uppercaseSentence.split("").forEach(letter => {
cc(letter);
});
console.log(count);
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a complete solution, especially a poorly written one.

Comment: @georg Thank you for the feedback, i really appreciate it! I am new here and want to learn how to write good answers that help other developers. Do you think my edit does a better job at answering the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
morse={
 "A": ".- ",
}
word="AAA";
morseWord=""
for(i=0;i<word.length;i++){
 morseWord+= morse[word[i]]
}
console.log(morseWord)
```